# CSS box model issue: box-sizing + 100% height + border + inline-block

Tags: google-chrome, css

Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WTcgt/

Why is the BOX1 pushed down by the amount of border of BOX2? Is this a bug?

Comment: 99.99999% of the time when something doesn't work as you expect, it is NOT a bug...

Comment: @Hidden If you meant CSS then I agree.

Comment: @Hidde, when something work not as user expects, it is usually implemented badly. I still can't understand why CSS styling is so counter-intuitive after more than 20 years of active development.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy I often see strange CSS constructions to achieve something very simple. However, because CSS has been used for such a long time, I think the barrier for people to create/use a new styling language (in combi with HTML or JS) is too high. Hopefully this whill change, because interactivity in webpages can be pushed to a much higher level with the technology of today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The box-sizing property is supported in Internet Explorer, Opera, and Chrome.

Firefox supports an alternative, the `-moz-box-sizing` property.

Safari supports an alternative, the `-webkit-box-sizing` property.

here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/WTcgt/2/

This is the behavior of **inline-block**:

> An inline block is placed inline (ie. on the same line as adjacent
>   content),  but it behaves as a block.

use `vertical-align:top` to avoid this problem. If we doesn't use vertical-align property then elements align in same line based on adjacent element. For more information read http://www.impressivewebs.com/inline-block/ and http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html

Answer (score 1):

Your boxes are *inline block* boxes and not just regular *inline* boxes, so their borders sort of act as "padding" in this aspect.

To be clear, since there is a top border on BOX2, it pushes the content area of BOX2 down (it *does not* bleed into the content area despite what may be implied by `box-sizing: border-box`!). This causes the content areas of all other inline block boxes on the same line to follow suit, as described in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html) (emphasis mine):

> **The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box start at the top and bottom of the content area**, and has nothing to do with the ['line-height'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height). But only the ['line-height'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) is used when calculating the height of the line box.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it not only says it is the correct behaviour, but also suggests the use of vertical-align. I know your answer seems more comprehensive, but I cannot accept two answers...